# Do I need Acquire/Release when Release only occures in locked region of a mutex?

Tags: rust, mutex, atomic

I'm writing a thread safe expandable array/vector with immutable data.

To receive the length of an element, I load an atomic integer. Reserving more space is guarded by a mutex. While reserving, I have to update the length. Since `reserve` is not called concurrently, do I need to store the value with release semantic? Is it possible, that instructions in a locked region are executed in another order as specified?

```rs
fn len(&self) -> usize {
    // Do we need Acquire or is Relaxed enough?
    self.len.load(atomic::Ordering::Acquire)
}

fn reserve(&self, additional: usize) {
    let _guard = self.mutex.lock();
    // this call happens while the mutex is locked. Is Relaxed fine or do we 
    // need Acquire?
    let current_len = self.len.load(atomic::Ordering::Relaxed);

    // ... do the reserving stuff ...

    // this call happens while the mutex is locked. Do we need Release semantic
    // or is Relaxed enough?
    self.len.store(current_len + additional, atomic::Ordering::Release);
}
```

I intentionally did not add the code to get the data, as this would lead to discussions that are not relevant here.

Comment: Hard to say, you need to provide more info on how `len` can be used later. If there are no others functions except `len` and `reserve`, then you can even use `relaxed` ordering everywhere. So what other operations thread are supposed to do on it and how? For what purpose you may need `len` function if returned value is racy? If array can be resized, accessing elements should require mutex lock anyway.

Comment: I can't see why `len` even needs to be atomic.  Every thread requesting it has to treat its value as outdated right from the moment it received it anyway, regardless of any ordering guarantees.